# Why does BASH_REMATCH not work for a quoted regular expression?

Tags: regex, bash

The code is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ foobarbletch =~ 'foo(bar)bl(.*)' ]]
 then
     echo "The regex matches!"
     echo $BASH_REMATCH
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
 fi
```

When I try to run it, it doesn't display anything:

```
bash-3.2$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash-3.2$ /bin/bash test_rematch.bash
bash-3.2$
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your bash REGEX, you should remove quotes. That's why that doesn't work.

If you have space, I recommend to use this way :

```
#!/bin/bash
x='foo bar bletch'
if [[ $x =~ foo[[:space:]](bar)[[:space:]]bl(.*) ]]
then
    echo The regex matches!
    echo $BASH_REMATCH      
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! but what shall I do if spacebar appears in the REGEX without using quotes?

Comment: @Firegun In addition, you can also represent a space with `\ ` or `' '` or `" "` (choose your poison) (the first one didn't show up well, it's backslash followed by space)

Comment: You can use quotes, just not around the regular expression metacharacters.  For instance, this works: `[[ foobarbletch =~ 'foo'('bar')'bl'(.*) ]]`  So feel free to quote any spaces - just not the whole string.

Comment: Also don't forget to escape literal quotes by a backslash.

Answer (score 25):

You can also assign the quoted regexp to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

x='foobarbletch'

foobar_re='foo(bar)bl(.*)'

if [[ $x =~ $foobar_re ]] ; then
    echo The regex matches!
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
```

This not only supports simple quoting but gives the regexp a name which can help readability.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to your debugging statement, `echo The regex matches!`, you should have noticed there is no problem with `BASH_REMATCH`, since the if statement evaluates to `false`.

In bash, regular expressions used with `=~` are unquoted. If the string on the right is quoted, then it is treated as a string literal.

If you want to include whitespaces in your regex's, then use the appropriate character classes, or escape your space if you want a space.