# How would I split a word from number in bash and create a variable from it?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a word `FOO123USR` I would like to split the `foo` and have it in its own variable and also the `123` in its own variable and finally I would like to get rid of the `USR`. I'm having trouble trying to accomplish this.

This is how my script looks so far but I am getting a blank output

```
#!/bin/bash


#var holding

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m'
var2=$(echo $START_VAR | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
var1=${START_VAR//[A-Z]/}


if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ];
then
echo -e "${RED} YOU MUST RUN AS ROOT USER ! ${NC}\n"
exit
fi

# We are getting the username here

read -p "Type the username <example: FOO123USR> [ENTER]: " START_VAR


echo "$va2"
echo "$var1"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes - I've been searching from a couple hours now. I'm not getting the output I'd like

Comment: Not much effort or information shown here. What's your criteria for splitting?

Comment: Look at `bash`'s support for regular expression matching and the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

Comment: Thank you @chepner I will look into this

Comment: [`BASH_REMATCH` by example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13150419/2908724).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this type of tinkering:

```
START_VAR=FOO123USR
var1=${START_VAR%%[0-9]*} # remove from first number to end
var2=${START_VAR//[A-Z]/} # remove ALL uppercase letters
```

More examples and info: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

:)
Dale

Comment: Thanks - tested this out and seemed to work but when implemented in my script the output returned blank. Any idea why ?

Comment: @D_22 in your updated script, why are you assigning variables `var1, var2` before the `read` statements..? also there is a typo while printing..

Comment: ahhh wow @spasic didn't notice the typo and I thought I'd be able to hold variables in spot. Still learning - thanks that solved the issue I was having