# Makefiles: syntax for regex matching as a conditional in an if statement

Tags: bash, makefile

I would like to add a line to a Makefile to check that the version of python that is installed is 2.7.X, preferably 2.7.9 or greater.  Specifically NOT 3.X.

I am a bit new to bash scripts and Makefiles, but it seems that Makefiles use a different syntax from normal bash or shell scripts, so I can't do what I would ordinarily do.  Something like:

```
if [[ $(python --version) =~ "Python 2.7.*" ]]; then echo "Version matched!"; fi
```

What is the syntax for matching a string to a regex in a Makefile?

I found Makefile patterns for substitution and `ifeq` and `ifneq`, but they don't seem to be able to do what I want them to do.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Your example wouldn't work in Bash either - don't quote the regex for it to work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150411/why-does-bash-rematch-not-work-for-a-quoted-regular-expression.

Comment: See also [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern) which has a glob-matcher in pure GNUmake syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
ret=`python -c 'import sys; print("%i" % (sys.hexversion<0x03000000))'`
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Python 2.7.x required"
else 
    echo "Python version is < 3.x"
fi
```

Comment: This could be simplified to `if python -c 'import sys; exit(sys.hexversion < 0x03000000)'; then ...`

Comment: My makefile is complaining that I'm missing a separator: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Comment: chepner, thanks for your contribution!  Got it working!

Comment: wp78de Thanks for the help!

Comment: `python --version 2>&1 | grep 'Python 2'` is a *lot* more compact than this mess.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write this test outside of any specific rule, you have to use make syntax.  Assuming you're using GNU make, you can write something like this:

```
$(or $(findstring Python 2.7.,$(shell python --version 2>&1)),$(error Python 2.7.x is required))
```

(oddly, `python --version` prints its version to stderr not stdout).

For more details on these functions see [Syntax of Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html).

Comment: I am having issues with the string being interpreted as a file path:  Python: can't open file '2.7.': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You probably transcribed it incorrectly then, this is correct syntax.

Comment: My example is meant to appear outside of any recipe, as makefile syntax not shell syntax.  For example, the first thing in a makefile before any targets are defined, and not part of a variable.  Just its own line, exactly as shown.  The solution wp78de shows is shell syntax, and is meant to appear within a recipe somewhere.

Comment: It also requires at least GNU make version 3.81 (for the `or` function.